# Excel VBA Chart is duplicated in error as a different chart type

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have been banging my head trying to understand how and why my excel vba code is generating some duplicate charts. To begin, when I run the macro as a stand-alone, the chart is generated perfectly and there are no issues, However, the chart(s) are created in about the 5th module and when I run the whole process from start to finish, I get a duplicate chart. I am trying to create a stacked column chart (which works fine by itself), but I also get a regular bar chart named the same with the same information in it. This also happens to another chart which is an Area chart. I am not sure if there is something=ng going on with memory or why a second chart is created. The data is name ranged and set up as follows in columns. The named range is "FTE_by_Co_Data"

Period(a1)   CoA FTE(b1)    CoB FTE (c1)
(a2)jan-15    (b2)15          (c2)30
etc.

Below is the code for the name range and chart creation.

```
'Name the Data Range for the Chart Source
        Sheets("FTE_by_Co").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="FTE_by_Co_Data", RefersTo:=Selection
        Sheets("FTE_by_Co").Select
        Range("FTE_by_Co_Data").Select


 'Creating New Chart
        Dim StffChartObject2 As ChartObject
        Set StffChartObject2 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Top:=50, Width:=600, Height:=400)
        StffChartObject2.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FTE_by_Co").Range("FTE_by_Co_Data")
        StffChartObject2.Name = "FTECoChart"
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("FTECoChart").Activate
        ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        Selection.Position = xlRight

'Add Chart Title
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("FTECoChart").Activate
        StffChartObject2.Chart.HasTitle = True
        StffChartObject2.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Staffing-Time Phase by FTE (avg. 157 hr/mo)"
```

Again, this works great when I just run this module by itself, but when I run it in sequence from Mod 1 through Mod 10 (this is in Mod 7), it always creates a duplicate chart that is not a stacked bar chart. Is there a memory issue happening? or is my code running to fast to create this? I have no clue why this would be happening. Thanks in advance for any assistance.
-Mike

Comment: Worked fine for me standalone. What is the "run it in sequence" part you mention?

Comment: What do you mean by **run it insequence from Mod 1 to Mod 10 (this is Mod 7)**? You have 10 similar codes?

Comment: Run it in sequence means that I have 10 modules (1-10) and when I click the button to generate the reports, It will start with Module 1, which is associated with Sheet one, then it goes to Module 2 that generates a different report on Sheet 2, etc. all the way to Module 10. The charts happened to be in Module 7 and 8 that I am having the issue with. The interesting thing is I have a chart in mod 6 that runs perfect when the whole macro is run from beg to end. If I just run mod 7 macro or mod 8 macro by themselves for testing, they are fine. But when I run it starting from Mod 1 thru 10 it err.

Comment: I was wondering if I could but a break/pause prior to running Module 7 and 8? but not sure.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition, where your code gets ahead of itself, and may skip a step (like setting chart type). Put a breakpoint at the start of the troublesome module, then run the whole sequence. When it gets to the breakpoint, step through. I presume the code will run fine. Experiment with the placement of the breakpoint to see where you can place it to stop the code, then resume full speed, not step by step. If this is possible, insert the command `DoEvents` at this point. This tells VBA to hang on and let Windows catch up with screen refreshing etc.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for the suggestion, that was it. I ended up moving the charting to the beginning and end of the code and now it works fine so far. Thanks again for the suggestion.